# Docker REST API : Create Image issue : Need help for parameter fromSrc:

Tags: rest, docker, docker-api

Hi Guys need your help.

I am creating an Image via docker REST API.

The [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#operation/ImageCreate) mentioned for parameter `fromSrc` following is the description :

> fromSrc: Source to import. The value may be a URL from which the image can be retrieved or - to read the image from the request body. This parameter may only be used when importing an image.

if anyone can suggest the meaning of `to read the image from the request body` part and how we can test [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.39/#operation/ImageCreate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to read the image from the request body

means that you have to put your image as `Json` into the body of your request.

The URL, in this case, will look like this `'.../images/create?fromSrc=-'`

To test this, you can use Restlet client or Postman, which are chrome extensions that let you build a request with a body.